# MFC application silently closes

Tags: c++, c, windows-xp

I am not sure what is going on. No error message displayed, though Windows error reporting is enabled. I even tried to log/show message from the dialog destructor. Not sure how to debug it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Process Dumper](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=4060) to get a memory dump on any process exit.  Postmortem debugging of the result might help identify the cause.

Comment: I will try it. I have no experience working with dump files. Any tips appreciated.

Comment: Does the problem reproduce with Debug build? If so you might get more info from that one.  For debugging process dumps I use WinDbg but I think the IDE can do it too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running this in the debugger? If it's an MFC application, it probably can be run in the Visual C++ debugger. If the program runs to completion with no errors, then the debugger -- as debuggers often do -- is masking the real problem. Suggest then using @Steve Townsend 's suggestion of Process Dumper.

Comment: I am running it in release mode without debugger.